# How to download multiple data.gov files at once

Tags: python, import, download, set

Just starting to work on large data sets and found a bunch of useful data linked @ https://data.ers.usda.gov/reports.aspx?ID=17854

I want to download each individual state in the dropdown, but the only way I am aware of is go to each page and download separately. Does anyone have a trick I can use to download all the state files at once?

Or is there a way to directly import the data sets on Python?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You'll probably need to use libraries such as beautiful soup or scrappy or mechanize

Comment: [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most popular, to my opinion is the [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) library.